# Recreating Plotly Express colouring with Normal Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to recreate a Plotly Express plot using normal Plotly objects (or rearrange my data in a way that it works with Plotly Express Facets). In Plotly express you can designate a column of data in a dataframe to act as an indicator of the colour of the line in the plot. The dataframe contains the metrics about a neural network imported from multiple CSVs. I need 5 plots for each of the 5 metrics, and on each plot each file shows a different line colour. Like this [image: A line graph showing data of metrics from a Neural Network]

I need either: Some way to reorganize the dataframe to work with Facets (5 facets each with an unknown number of lines where each line represents a metric from a specific file) OR a way to colour each line from normal plotly so each plot doesn't end up looking like this[image: Another plot of a line graph, but this one is indecipherable due to all the lines being the same colour]

So I have this code. The Plotly Express code is commented out and the uncommented code results in the all blue plot seen above (there is only one append trace at the moment because I saw no point in making all 5 subplots when they all end up looking like the picture).

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
path = "G:\GDL\Metrics"
csvs = os.listdir(path)
data=[]
#import all the CSV data (currently using the first 10 as a test)
for i in range(10):
    filepath=path+"\\"+csvs[i]
    with open(filepath) as csvfile:
        reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            #The way the CSVs are structured, this if statement checks to see if there's numerical data (as long as it isn't the first row)
            if i>0 and row[0][0:1] != ',':
                temp=row[0].split(',')
                temp.append(csvs[i])
                data.append(temp)
            #If it is the first row, import it. This will be the column titles in the dataframe
            if i == 0:
                temp=row[0].split(',')
                temp.append("File")
                data.append(temp)
#Make the dataframe, where the first entry in data is the names of the columns, and the rest is the data
df=pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns=data[0])
#convert all the columns in the new dataframe to numbers (from strings)
df[["Loss","Epoch","Precision","Recall","F-Score","IoU"]] = df[["Loss","Epoch","Precision","Recall","F-Score","IoU"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
print(df)
df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
# df.sort_values(by="Epoch")
# fig = px.line(df, x="Epoch",y="IoU",color="File")
# fig.show()
fig=  make_subplots(rows=6, cols=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["Epoch"],y=df["Recall"]),row=1,col=1)
fig.show()
```

As for what my DataFrame looks like it is:

Epoch, Loss, Precision, Recall, F-Score, IoU, File

10, 0.01095, 0.9098492, 0.8972, 0.88912, 0.48142, FILENAME

[...]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're leaving out some important information here. Is your data of a long or wide format? Does `px.line(df, x="Epoch",y="IoU",color="File")` really give you the desired result? If you share a sample of your data like this, you're increasing your chances of receiving a useful answer considerably.

Comment: Do you mind to provide an [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @vestland I believe my data is in long form, I'll edit to add what the data frame looks like. Also, yes, that line does give me my desired result (a line graph showing the progression of a metric over the number of epochs, where the line colour is determined by file name uniqueness)